# How to diagnose and fix extremely laggy VNC experience

Tags: pi-4

I am using a Raspberry Pi 4 with an external SSD to boot from. I am finding that when I connect to it remotely and try to browse the web with VNC it is just hopelessly laggy. Like seconds of delays between things happening, very slow and gradual page updates, really unusable when what you are seeing is so far detached from the actual webpage state.

I am assuming this is a combination of networking, the VNC protocol, and my hardware.

I guess my question is where do I start looking to improve this? Should I use a different browser than chromium? Is there a way to get the PI to use a GFX card so the ram isnt tied up in that?

Open to all ideas. I have gone through many of the lists for common ways to speed up a PI.

Comment: I would start by relpacing the Pi with a regular PC with Debian. If VNC works fine then, it would be clearly a Pi issue. Otherwise it's hard to tell what the problem is, and there's a risk your question will be closed as "unrelated to the Pi".